# Optimise android app for slow network connection

Tags: android, performance

I am currently working on an android app and it's already on production. I have noticed that almost quarter of my users are using slow network connection. So I have taken up this project to optimise my app for slow network connection.

Here are the changes I have in my mind ::

1) Decrease size of the payload that comes from backend (in case slow network is detected) to just include must needed details.

2) For requests whose responses are same for certain parameters, I store them for certain time.

3) Add caching in for images and content that do not change for certain time.

4) Store list contents in sql DB that change over time slowly and only fetch the diff part accumulated over time.

Now here is what I would like to know:

1) From your experience, please suggest me more things that can be done for handling slow network connections.

2) When should  switch the app to light-mode (for handling slow connections)? Is it when the user starts the app or while he is using it and I keep a listener for net speed ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what features your application provide because the recommendations may differ for different applications. However you may also want to consider following.

- Optimize your connection timeouts and retry accordingly. Its better to have short timeout and multiple retries on faster network vs longer timeout and less retries on slower network.
- If you are storing data that otherwise was not required for fast network, then have you taken care of security risks of storing data offline (encryption, deletion of data, phone memory, etc...)
- In case you are using SQL DB, make sure to use bulk insert and transactional queries if you have a high number of records to update.
- Instead of a continuous listener for network speed, utilise your own network queues for switching between online/offline modes. If your request queue is growing high or if there were more timeouts in last one minute.
- Some networks are fast but they just have high latency period. You need to handle such cases accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Most of the data I am storing are not sensitive and hence I believe does not require encryption. However, there are some keys that I store in shared preference. Do I need to encrypt them too ?

Comment: Yes if the keys are sensitive data then do encrypt before storing. Its easy for somebody to get hold of your shared preferences file and read it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following to overcome low network speed.

1. Optimize image sizes at the server. This is not good to show high quality images in grid like views (I would suggest you preparing a small image sizes for gridView or etc... instead of images with real size).
2. Add Cashing for images/content response based on user supplied parameters for a while.
3. Handling request queues and connections timeout.
4. Ask a DBA to optimize your database queries. Adding a proper index on your tables may boost the performance of your SQL queries

Comment: Thank you. I have started building a service in my backend to resize the images as per requirements